# JQuery: Combining animate CSS and fadeIn

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fadein

This is my script:

```
$("#headerimage").animate({marginLeft:"0"},300);
```

I want to add "fadeIn" as well to start simultaneously and at the exact same speed. How is this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By animating the opacity:

```
$("#headerimage").animate({
    marginLeft: 0,
    opacity   : 1
}, 300);
```

If it's hidden with display:none, show it first:

```
$("#headerimage").css({
    opacity : 0,
    display : 'block' // or whatever
}).animate({
    marginLeft: 0,
    opacity   : 1
}, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#headerimage").animate({
    marginLeft:"0",
    opacity: 1
},300);
```